# Is there some kind of JSON_FORCE_ARRAY instead of JSON_FORCE_OBJECT?

Tags: php, arrays, json

JSON_FORCE_OBJECT is a flagged being passed to the famous json_encode function in PHP.

As documention says:

> JSON_FORCE_OBJECT (integer) Outputs an object rather than an array
>   when a non-associative array is used. Especially useful when the
>   recipient of the output is expecting an object and the array is empty.
>   Available since PHP 5.3.0.

I couldn't find a flag to force the oposite. is there any programmatic way?

Comment: Would something like `json_encode(array_values($ar))` suit your needs?

Comment: If you dont say JSON_FORCE_OBJECT  flag, non-associative array will be coded as array

Comment: @JonStirling It didn't work. I will try to produce a code sample and add to the question.

Comment: @splash58 same about your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Encoding an object as a non-associative array is a lossy operation. The object property names/array keys are lost. This is why `json_encode()` doesn't provide a way to encode an object as a non-associative array.

Since PHP 5.4 your class can implement the [`JsonSerializable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) interface. The method declared by this interface ([`jsonSerialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php)) is called by `json_encode()` and it returns the object data that needs to be put in the text representation produced by `json_encode()`.

If you want to encode only the values of an object's properties (without the property names) you can implement it like this:

```
class MyClass implements JsonSerializable
{
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return array_values((array)$this);
    }
}
```

Please notice that you won't be able to restore the object (using `json_decode()`) from the output of `json_encode()` because some information was lost during the encoding (the names of the properties).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is to ensure you have a simple non-associative array in PHP.

```php
$simple_array = array_values($associative_array);
$json = json_encode($simple_array);
unset($simple_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this behavior is desired for a possibly empty array, you may need to do the following:

```
$json = empty($inpArray) ? '[]' : json_encode($inpArray);
```